No limited time between posts
As I am involved in a few SE sites, I have noticed that basically all have a time limit between when you can post again, presumably to stop people spamming. For example, Super Users is 30 minutes, I think.
The thing is, Server Fault doesn’t have a time limit!
I don’t, but if I wanted to, I could post question after question repeatedly ten times in a minute, if I (or anyone) could type that fast!
So, I tried looking into this and found nothing.
Is there a reason for this or is it just how this site works?
Just kinda strange is all…

As far as I know, this is still accurate.
Moderators can take action for other situations.
